# moving the whole word to next line when there is no free space

Tags: tables, line-breaking, hyphenation

Is there any option in tabular that can move the whole word to the next line whenever the length of the word is greater than the fixed cell size?

Currently I use

```
\begin{tabular}{ | p{2cm} | }
```

And that results in this format

```
+---------+
| First t-|
| hing    |
+---------+
```

However I am looking for this shape

```
+---------+
| First   |
| thing   |
+---------+
```

Comment: the answers recommending `\raggedright` are on target.  but i find the hyphenation you show to be very strange indeed!  if that actually happens (as opposed to being simply a made-up example), the hyphenation in the rest of your document must also be questionable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `\raggedright`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  First longerword & First longerword \\
  Second Thing & Second Thing \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|}
  First longerword & First longerword \\
  Second Thing & Second Thing \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The second `tabular` will include a `\raggedright` in each cell of the `p` column, which will avoid the hyphenation.

Note that you need to load the `array` package for this to work. You also need `\arraybackslash` in at least the last column to have `\\` correctly end the table row.

Output:

[image: output]

If you need this for just a few cells, you can also use `\raggedright` in these cells:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  \raggedright First longerword & \raggedright\arraybackslash First longerword \\
  Second Thing & Second Thing \\
\end{tabular}
```

If it's more than one column, you can also define your own column type:

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}

\begin{tabular}{|R|R|}
  First longerword & First longerword \\
  Second Thing & Second Thing \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: If I have more than one column, should I use `\raggedright}p{2cm}|` multiple times?

Comment: You want to add `\arraybackslash` right after `\raggedright` in the column declaration. (Try adding a column before the existing one.)

Comment: @mahmood: see my updated answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thanks, I completely forgot about that! Answer updated.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to avoid hypehenation by setting `\hyphenpenalty=10000`. I have defined a new column with this setting. You can add it in  individual cells too with `p` columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\hyphenpenalty=10000}p{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  First longerword & First longerword \\
  Second Thing & Second Thing \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|D{2cm}|D{2cm}|}    
  First longerword & First longerword \\
  Second Thing & Second Thing \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\raggedright` is essential anyway.